# Deleting Images from Imageview In IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have array of images; in scrollview when I press button delete button will place on the top of image view when press the cross button the imageview not get removed or fade out. How can I resolve these issues?

Here is my code

```
   -(void)getimagefunction
    {
        BusinessUser *busUser = [BusinessUser getBusinessUser];
        NSLog(@"%@", _GalleryimageDictionary);
        _GalleryimageArry =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *resultarray =[_GalleryimageDictionary valueForKey:@"images"];
        if ([resultarray count] != 0) {
            NSString*baseurl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",BaseUrl,@"uploads/BusinessImages/"];
            NSString *businessid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lld",busUser.business_id];
            NSString*checkstring =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseurl,businessid];
            for(int i=0; i<resultarray.count;i++){
                _finalString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",checkstring,[resultarray objectAtIndex:i]];
                NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[_finalString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL]])];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                
                [_GalleryimageArry addObject:image];
            }
            
            for(int i=0; i<_GalleryimageArry.count;i++){
                _imageV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * i/2*0.7, 0, 100, 100)];
                
                self.Crossbtn =[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_imageV.image.size.width/2+80,0,20,20)];
                UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CrossImageICon"];
                [self.Crossbtn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                _imageV.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
              _imageV.image = [_GalleryimageArry objectAtIndex:i];
                [_imageV setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
                _imageV.tag = i;
                self.Crossbtn.tag =i;
                [self.Crossbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapMethod:)];
                [_imageV addGestureRecognizer:tap];
                [self.imageV addSubview:self.Crossbtn];
                if ([_crossstringshow isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
                      self.Crossbtn.hidden =NO;
                }
              else
              {
                    self.Crossbtn.hidden =YES;
              }
                [self.imageGalleryscroll addSubview:_imageV];
                [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
            }
            self.imageGalleryscroll.delegate = self;
            index=0;
            
            
            
            self.imageGalleryscroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame) * _GalleryimageArry.count/2*0.7, CGRectGetHeight(self.imageGalleryscroll.frame));
            
            [self.imageGalleryscroll setPagingEnabled:YES];
            
            [self.imageGalleryscroll setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
            self.imageGalleryscroll.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
            
        }
        
        else
        {  [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
            //  self.business_galleryimg.hidden=NO;
            self.imageGalleryscroll.hidden =YES;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    -(void)deleteImage:(UIButton *)sender
    {id superv = [sender superview];
        [superv removeFromSuperview];
        
    
    [self.GalleryimageArry removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
```

Comment: After deleting image view, are you resetting complete scrollview? Best way to do this using tableview or collection view. So that you can simply reload the tableview/collectionview.

Comment: can u ples some suggestion code i am new for the development

Comment: Did you check [superv removeFromSuperview] is image view?

Comment: yes removing cross buton  but the image is not get removed

Comment: Try this 

for (UIView * view in _scrollView.subviews) {
    if (view.tag == superv.tag) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.GalleryimageArry removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    }
}

Comment: can u pls update the answer

Comment: @ammu there are many examples/ tutorials available. Few of them are https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started , https://medium.com/yay-its-erica/creating-a-collection-view-swift-3-77da2898bb7c

Comment: the code its show error

Comment: venkadesh but looking for objective c without using collection view i have placed the array in scrollview how to remove the particular image view based on the index

Comment: @ammu,please check the answer, i haven't tested it. but i suppose it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the button click you need to retrieve the button tag, and compare it with all the subviews of scrollview, also you need to check if the subview is an imageview since you have the same tag for button and imageview.

```
    -(void)deleteImage:(UIButton *)sender{    
         for (UIView * view in self.imageGalleryscroll.subviews) {
             if (view.tag == sender.tag && [subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                  [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
```

Updated answer, since the paging is enabled for the scrollview we can use the same to get the index of the selected object from array.

```
      -(void)deleteImage:(UIButton *)sender{    

       int index = imageGalleryscroll.contentOffset.x / imageGalleryscroll.frame.size.width;

         for (UIView * view in self.imageGalleryscroll.subviews) {
             if (view.tag == sender.tag && [view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
                  [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
        self.GalleryimageArry removeObjectAtIndex:index];

    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169660/discussion-on-answer-by-vinaykrishnan-deleting-images-from-imageview-in-ios).